# trying to pass list of guids to table

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have table where one of column(`SelectedIds`) datatype is `uuid` array and i am passing the same guid's using RAW sql insert statement like as below

```
foreach(var designHubProjectSpaceType in designHubProjectSpaceTypes)
{
    var warningJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(designHubProjectSpaceType.Warnings).Replace("'", "''", StringComparison.Ordinal);
    var initialObjectJson  = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(designHubProjectSpaceType.InitialObject).Replace("'", "''", StringComparison.Ordinal);
    var patchJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(designHubProjectSpaceType.Patches).Replace("'", "''", StringComparison.Ordinal);

    migrationBuilder.Sql($@"INSERT INTO ""DesignHubProjectSpaceTypes""(""Id"", ""ProjectNumber"", ""ExcludedIds"", ""SelectedIds"", ""IsBasedOnMaster"", ""Warnings"", ""InitialObject"", ""Patches"") "
                       + $@"VALUES ('{designHubProjectSpaceType.Id}', '{designHubProjectSpaceType.ProjectNumber}', [], '{designHubProjectSpaceType.SelectedIds.Select(a => a).ToList()}', '{designHubProjectSpaceType.IsBasedOnMaster}', 
                         '{warningJson}', '{initialObjectJson}', '{patchJson}' )");
}
```

and here `designHubProjectSpaceType.SelectedIds.Select(a => a).ToList()` are having list of guid's and that is what i am trying to pass into `SelectedIds` column. But when i tried to see the sql string that is passed, I noticed that in place of those guids `system.Collections.Generic.List[System.Guid]` is passed like as shown in below image

[image]

and these are guid's that `designHubProjectSpaceType.SelectedIds` is holding and i don't know where i am doing wrong here.

[image]

Could any one please let me know any idea why list of guids are passed as type, I am using postgreSQL as DB and using EFCore. I have put the above code in migration file.

below is the table structure

[image]

getting an error with this `'{string.Join(',', selectedIds)}'`
[image]

Comment: Hey - what exactly exception You getting?

Comment: What is that for database that u can insert arrays?

Comment: @PiotrŻak getting an exception like `syntax error at or near "["` and instead list of guids `system.Collections.Generic.List[System.Guid]`

Comment: @spzvtbg  the database is postgresql and the column data type id `uuid[]` and i updated the same in question

Comment: designHubProjectSpaceType.SelectedIds.Select(a => a).ToList().ToString() = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[...] and not [ {xxx-xxx-xx-x-x}, {...}, ...]

Comment: Are u tried - remove - { } - between '' ?

Comment: if you remove `{}` then this is passed as string `designHubProjectSpaceType.SelectedIds.Select(a => a).ToList().`

Comment: Without error? - so maybe there is solution to holds it at string

Comment: @PiotrŻak, if you pass with out `{}` in insert statement this `designHubProjectSpaceType.SelectedIds.Select(a => a).ToList()` is passed as string

Comment: have u tryied to join the guids in a string format that u need

Comment: the datatype is uuid array actually

Comment: **This is not the way to pass values into SQL. Use proper parameterization**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of the code is that it is **converting a list to a string** by calling ToString() implicitly by string interpolation. Checkout this example:

```cs
Guid[] selectedIds = new Guid[]{
    Guid.NewGuid(),
    Guid.NewGuid()
};

string error = $@"'{selectedIds.Select(a => a).ToList()}'";
Console.WriteLine($"Error: {error}");

// Tweak the following string interpolations according to the target SQL syntax you needed.

// Join string with single quotes
string correct = $@"'{{{string.Join(',', selectedIds)}}}'";
Console.WriteLine($"Format 1: {correct}");

// Putting `{}` over uuid, and adding the list into a `[]`:
string correct2 = $@"'[{string.Join(',', selectedIds.Select(id => "{" + id + "}"))}]'";
Console.WriteLine($"Format 2: {correct2}");
```

Outputs:

```sh
Error: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]'
Format 1: '{5e4b44c2-f087-44db-98b0-95da1ae20ed7,1153d836-baee-4ba4-85f1-6f0c08934135}'
Format 2: '[{5e4b44c2-f087-44db-98b0-95da1ae20ed7},{1153d836-baee-4ba4-85f1-6f0c08934135}]'
```

On the side, it might be easier if you output the sql you are sending to console or logging for debugging.

Comment: I mentioned sql output what actually is going to send to the db in question and i will try yours

Comment: @EnigmaState :-) I wasn't complain about the info in your question. it is good there's a lot details there. I assumed that you run the query to get the error and I was just suggesting to output the string locally to compare with the SQL wanted in form of string.

Comment: the output it is actually looking for like this `{list of guids separated by commas}` but looks like with yours one we are just passing `ids separated by commas`

Comment: Okay. thanks for the info. Just try this: `string correct = $@"'{{{string.Join(',', selectedIds)}}}'";`

Comment: Could you please explain what is your expected sql string look like for uuid array? Is it single quoted list like `'guid1, guid2'` or maybe `[{guid1}, {guid2}]` or so? That will help.

Comment: this is the expected format `{uuid,uuid}`

Comment: Okay, then, I had some lucky hit it by `Format 1` in the answer above. Could you please try that?